# Как рандомно открыть фотки в Телеграмм Боте на Python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Помогите с рандомом фоток на Питоне в Телеграмм боте)

У меня есть проект бота, который при нажатии на любую инлайн кнопку должен открывать картинки (в зависимости от количества фоток в папке).
Если человек нажмет на кнопку Москва то рандомно бот должен выбрать папку в папке Москва (да, в папке Москва есть папки в которых хранятся фотки) и отправить пользователю, а так в папке хранится txt файл с текстом который должен быть написан вместе[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете ли Вы показать код в виде текста, а не скриншотами?

Answer (score 0):

допустим нажата кнопка Москва.

```
import os, random

dirname = ‘user/path/moscow’ # указываем полный путь к папке москвы
files = os.listdir(dirname)  # получаем список всех фото
photo = str(random.choices(files)) # рандомно выбираем фото из списка
bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, open(dirname + photo, 'rb')) # отправляем фото
```

Comment: Спасибо, но вы видимо не до конца прочитали сообщение. У меня в папке Москва присутствуют еще папки (где как раз таки фотографии) с порядковыми номерами от 1 до ... Мне надо чтобы бот рандомно выбирал папку (например 43), и была кнопка для псодедующего просмотра папок

Answer (score 0):

Ниже написал функцю, которая будет возвращать файл с рандомным фото. На вход принимает название города, по умолчанию стоит Москва

```
import os, random

def get_random_photo(city='moscow'):
    dirname = f‘user/path/{city} # начальная папка
    dirs = os.listdir(dirname) # получаем список папок
    random_dir = str(random.choices(dirs)) # выбираем рандомную папку
    photo = str(random.choices(random_dir)) # выбираем рандомное фото
    return photo # возвращаем

random_photo = get_random_photo() # на выходе строка пр. "3.jpg"
```